# Actionbar with multiple fragments: Fragment Layout shifts up

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Actionbar that runs the below code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    bar.addTab(bar.newTab()
        .setText("Fragment_1")
        .setTabListener(
                new TabListener<ExampleFragment>(this, "Fragment_1", ExampleFragment.class)));
  .
  .
  .
   <Listener code that add the Fragment via FragmentTransaction>..
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    MenuItem mSearchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_fragments);
    edit = (EditText) mSearchItem.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.edit);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }

}
```

My menu `options_menu.xml` is like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

   <item
       android:id="@+id/menu_fragments"
       android:actionLayout="@layout/fragment"
       android:showAsAction="always">
   </item>

</menu>
```

I have a fragment as below:

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    return view;
  }
}
```

And my `fragment.xml` is like below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dip"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Button" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now this issue is, when I call the Fragment, the layout in `fragment.xml` gets shifted up  when I choose to type something.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Never mind. I got the problem.

It was a stupid `<requestFocus/>` on an EditText Widget in the Actionbar's `@layout/main` xml file. Removed it and now works.

Edit:
Sorry, the problem persisted, but I caught hold of the solution at last.

Include,

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` **into your activity which hosts the fragment(s)** in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

The layout won't shift if you use a keypad/numpad.